# Redis miss most of the request

Tags: redis, redis-server

I found strange behavior while using Redis. Sometimes most requests to Redis are miss.

I set eviction policies to `allkeys-lru` if I understand correctly if memory usage is full Redis will evict less recent use key. so it may the cause of this behavior but >50% miss I think it is too much.

Is anyone found the same behavior, or can explain what is the cause of this behavior?

Red: miss / Green: hit
[image]